# FFMPEG freeze last frame until end time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an animation that gets turned into a bunch of png's. I am trying to keep the animation under 2 seconds. My users have a timeline where they can specify how long they want it to be visible.

I take about 120 screenshots that will mean 120 frames gets passed through at 60 frames per second, which is 2 seconds. The user may want the text to be there for 5 seconds.

My goal is to take the last frame and have it stay in the video until the specified end time.

How can I take the 120th frame and keep it in the video until then using FFMPEG.

Here is my generated command below.

```
ffmpeg
        -i "http://storycreator.co:8181/unsplash/photo-1572800578930-fd1013b506c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE1OTQxfQ" 
        -i "http://storycreator.co:8181/unsplash/photo-1573070303620-ea2602590e96?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE1OTQxfQ" 
        -framerate 60
        -i "./e4634ba0-00fd-11ea-ac54-9d3618dabf3e-%d.png"
        -i "./watermark.png"
        -f lavfi
        -i color=c=white:s=1080x1080

        -ss 17.75
        -i "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/708135835/stream?client_id=d8976b195733c213f3ead34a2d95d1c1"

        -filter_complex "
        [0:v]scale=1983.2727272727273:1326.5454545454545[ovr1], 
        [1:v]scale=1283.3587786259543:1923.6641221374048[ovr2], 
        [2:v]scale=1080:1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(0/TB)[ovr3], 
        [3:v]scale=458:58[ovr4],

        [4:v][ovr1]overlay=-780.3636807528409:-69.33335182883523:enable='between(t,0,3.5799999999999996)'[int1],
        [int1][ovr2]overlay=-79.3167603470897:-45.92176131619752:enable='between(t,3.5900000000000003,15)'[int2], [int2][ovr3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[int3], [int3][ovr4]overlay=W-500:H-100:enable='between(t,0,15)'

        [out]
        "
        -map "[out]"
        -vcodec libx264
        -crf 27
        -preset veryfast
        -map 5:0
        -t 00:00:15
        /var/folders/m1/4swfw09137x2b3d2h3_y5wmw0000gn/T/tmp-9351clz63oHIdLu7/fc160990-00fd-11ea-ac54-9d3618dabf3e.mp4
```

Comment: What is the specified end time in this command: 5 seconds or 15?

Comment: I just want to say thanks @Gyan I always see you answering FFMPEG questions and you have helped me a lot.

`between(t,0,5)` is the animated text which has the sequence of .png images. The sequence is only 120 frames aka 2 seconds. In my editor, the animated text should stick for 5 seconds. Instead of taking 300+ screenshots Id rather just keep the last frame so the rendering is faster.

Comment: `[int2][ovr3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[int3]` --> this should already cause the last frame of the 2nd input to be repeated till 5 seconds if it's shorter. What are you seeing? Also, for all filters which end with an output label, terminate with a semi colon, not comma.